# jQuery - How can I bind events to an element and prevent them from conflicting such that they do not undo one another?

Tags: jquery, bind, addeventlistener, mousemove, unbind

I am working on a timeline, and I have ran into an interesting problem which does not appear to be possible to resolve by combining the events into a single task. Please see the mark up below.

My goal is to stop the `mousemove` event from unbinding the hover mousemove event after triggering the `mousedown` & `mousemove` event. Is there another event type that could help bypass this issue?

NOTE*** Event binds after `mouseout` event takes place, if mouse stays inside the hover area after `mousedown` event is finished, then you will see the event stop triggering.

```js
var tl = $('#timeline');

tl.hover(function(){
 $(this).mousemove(function(e){
  console('hovering mouse moving : ' +e.pageX)
 });
}).mouseout(function(){
 $(this).unbind('mousemove');
});

// Timeline Mouse Down Event
tl.mousedown(function(e){
 $(this).mousemove(function(e){
  console('mousedown moving')
 });
}).mouseup(function(){
 $(this).unbind('mousemove');
}).mouseout(function(){
 $(this).unbind('mousemove');
});

function console(txt){
  $('#console').html(txt);
}
```

```css
#timeline {height:100px;width:100%;background-color:#333;}
#console {border: 1px solid #333;padding:0.5em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div id='timeline'></div>
<br>
<div id='console'>Log</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Should I combine the events like this? Or leave it like the example above?

```js
var tl = $('#timeline');

tl.hover(function(){
 $(this).mousemove(function(e){
  // task runs here
 }).mouseout(function(){
   $(this).unbind('mousemove');
  });
}).mousedown(function(e){
 $(this).mousemove(function(e){
  // task runs here
 }).mouseup(function(){
   $(this).unbind('mousemove');
  }).mouseout(function(){
   $(this).unbind('mousemove');
  });
});
```